# Recode several variables into new variables in spss or r

Tags: r, spss

I have data from an go/no go experiment with 200 variables.

1. trial1 to trial100 where 0 describes that it is a no go trial and 1 to 15 that it is a go trial. No go trials and go trials are randomized.
2. answer1 to answer100 recordes the reactiontime (with -1 as missing)

I would like to recode the reactiontime into new variables GoTrialRT1 to 100 (if the trial is 1 to 15) and NoGoTrialRT1 to 100 if the trial is 0. Is it a way to do this with spss syntax or in r?

| ID | trial1 | trial2 | trial3 | trial.. | answer1 | answer2 | answer3 | answer.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 14 | .. | 489 | 363 | 700 | .. |
| 2 | 0 | 6 | 15 | .. | 368 | 967 | 1201 | .. |
| 3 | 8 | 0 | 10 | .. | -1 | 671 | 890 | .. |
| 4 | 2 | 7 | 0 | .. | 358 | 353 | -1 | .. |

Comment: Please edit your post to add the expected results in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will put the value of `answerX` in `NoGoTrialRTX` if the `trialX` value was 0 or in `GoTrialRTX` if the `trialX` value was larger than 0 (leaving the other one empty). If `trialX` was missing both `NoGoTrialRTX` and `GoTrialRTX` will remain empty:

```
do repeat trl = trial1 to trial100
      /ans = answer1 to answer100
      /Ng = NoGoTrialRT1 to NoGoTrialRT100
      /Yg = GoTrialRT1 to GoTrialRT100.
if trl = 0 Ng=ans.
if trl > 0 Yg=ans.
end repeat.
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it a way to sort the variables so that GoTrialRT1 to GoTrial100 is listed first and then NoGoTrialRT1 to NoGoTrialRT100 ?

Comment: Sure it can be done but since this is a completely different question, you should start a new post with it.